# How visual studio 2015 build android project

Tags: android, build, visual-studio-2015

I need an expert's explanation about how visual studio 2015 builds the android application. Before going to develop a complex and costly application with Visual Studio 2015, knowing the build process will help to avoid bugs that cannot be resolved.

Do they build the project as a java binary code or native code? If they use a java build, is that process the same as the gradle build? If they use native, what is the steps involved with the building process?

How Xamarin involves with the building process?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xamarin in Visual Studio you will get a native application after build so the performances of it are the same. You can also use Cordova in Visual Studio 2015 but then application you build are not native.

You can read more about Android Build process of Xamarin [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/).

Comment: Did they use Xamarin builders for Visual studio as well?

Comment: Visual studio 2015 has full Xamarin integrated but you need to pay for it in order to use Xamarin.